# Apache2 Configuration: Execute if mod is enabled?

Tags: apache, configuration, apache-config, apache-modules

Is there a possibility to execute a part of a configuration file in Apache 2.4 only if a specific mod (e.g. mod_wsgi) is enabled?

Comment: That part will work only if the respective module is enabled. Like headers, gd and rewrite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache provides `IfModule` for this, see the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html).

Use it like this:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```